# where am i wrong why isnt it connecting?

Tags: php, mysql

```
   {<?

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product")
or die(mysql_error());


$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );


echo "product: ".$row['product'];
echo " price  : ".$row['price'];

?>}
```

Comment: check your short tag in php.ini other wise, use <?php also look at this -> ?>}..what }{ this is for?? and yes about the conn handling to the db

Comment: what error are you getting ? are you enabled short tag ?

Comment: Are you getting an error message through `mysql_error()`? Can you post what you're trying to accomplish here? And why are there squiggly brackets surrounding the code?

Comment: what is the error message you are gtting?

Comment: Where *are* you wrong?  Are you getting an error message?  If so, why don't you post it???  What's the funny "`{<?`" thing you're doing?  Why not the standard "`<?php`" syntax?  Your syntax is wrong: you need to include "`$conn`" in your calls.  But you shouldn't be using these calls anyway: use PDO or [MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) instead!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have to store your connection in a variable.

```
<?php

$dbconn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db", $dbconn);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product", $dbconn);

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "product: ".$row['product'];
echo " price  : ".$row['price'];

?>
```

It's very recommended to use `mysqli` or PDO instead, since the `mysql` extension is now deprecated in PHP.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  But the real issue is the OP needs to throw away whatever example code he's got and use `<?php` tags and [MySQLI](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) or PDO instead.  And [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_stmt_init.asp) :)  IMHO...

Comment: I am surprised this answer got upvote. He is using `mysqli` syntax in `mysql`. In `mysql`, resource link comes after the sql, not before.

Comment: @itachi OK, fine, the resource link and the query string should be swapped. You actually expect someone to remember such a stupid and insignificant detail ? If you noticed this, you could've edited it. Never mind, I'll do it...

Comment: @RaduMurzea in programming, nothing is stupid and insignificant. This change of order can make a whole application stop working.

Comment: in plain old `mysql_*` functions you don't have to store the connection (although it is good practice). When calling `mysql_*` functions and not passing a connection, they will use the last connection opened.